# SQL value from the database between 11th of last month to the 10th of this month

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

Hi All I'm trying to get the sum the values from a SQL database from the 11th of last month to the 10th of this month ie.

```
SELECT SUM(pay) AS month_pay 
FROM payaccounts 
WHERE dates BETWEEN 11th of last month and the 10th of this month
```

I am at currently using this statement to find the values from last month but now i've been told we need to change this to the 11th.

```
SELECT SUM(pay) AS month_pay 
FROM payaccounts 
WHERE (DATEPART(m, date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, - 1, GETDATE()))) AND 
      (DATEPART(yy, date) = DATEPART(yy, DATEADD(m, - 1, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: Looks like you are using SQL Server. What version of SQL Server is this for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like this to get the dates you want.

```
select dateadd(day, 10, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)) [11 of last],
       dateadd(day, 10, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) [11 of current]
```

And use them in your query like this.

```
SELECT SUM(pay) AS month_pay 
FROM payaccounts 
WHERE date >= dateadd(day, 10, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)) and
      date < dateadd(day, 10, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` (twice) to compute these dates:

```
SELECT SUM(pay) AS month_pay 
FROM payaccounts 
WHERE dates BETWEEN
    DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20001211') and
    DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010110')
```

However, if your `dates` column also contains times, I'd instead recommend:

```
SELECT SUM(pay) AS month_pay 
FROM payaccounts 
WHERE dates >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20001211') and
      dates < DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010111')
```

(Where we're now specifying a semi-open interval using `>=` and `<`)

The `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` trick is about finding two dates with the correct relationship between them. So, e.g. when adding and subtracting months, then the relationship that the 11th December 2000 bore to 1st January 2001 is "the 11th of last month". And similarly, 10th January 2001 bore the relationship "the 10th of this month".

Comment: Ah yea, the old ">= StartDate < EndDate+1". FYI, be careful with that, if you have an end date with 12/31/2999 in place of infintiy, this variant will fail (in this example it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

Use your asp classic code to create two datetime variables.  Make one of them, @StartDate, the 11th of the previous month.  Make the second one, @EndDate, the 11th of this month.  That's right, the 11th, not the 10th.  Then your query will contain this:

```
where [date] >= @StartDate
and [date] < @EndDate
```

This will ensure that the time component of your date field is taken into account.  Also, your query will run faster because you are not using functions in the where clause.